# How to maintain a landscape aspect ratio with getUserMedia on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm using `getUserMedia` with the following constraints:

```
var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
        width: 960,
        height: 540,
    }
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(...);
```

This works when using desktops or when using mobile devices while they are in **landscape** mode. However, when rotating the mobile device to **portrait** mode, the video object loses the aspect ratio:

When the device is held as **Landscape**:

[image]

When the device is held as **Portrait**:

[image]

This happens both on iOS and Android devices, on Chorme, Safari and Samsung browser.

I tried playing around with the constraints `aspectRatio`, `min`, `ideal` as suggested by [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints), but it seems these constraints are of no effect at all.

Is there any way to always maintain the aspect ratio as 1.777 even if the mobile device is rotated as portrait mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that you can use reversed `aspectRatio` when in **Portrait** mode.

I use this constraints in **Landscape** mode:

```
mediaConstraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
  video: {
    aspectRatio: 16/9
  }
};
```

and this constraints in **Portrait** mode:

```
mediaConstraints: MediaStreamConstraints = {
  video: {
    aspectRatio: 9/16
  }
};
```

The caveat of this solution is you have to detect orientation change and call again `getUserMedia()`, losing your stream.

Also if you are recording the stream, you should prevent screen rotation with [`ScreenOrientation.lock()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock) (not working in Safari) so user is not able to reset stream by rotating device while recording.